# Rails tests lead to different results in apparently identical cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

The following class is undergoing tests, with a fixture and the test assertions.

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  validates :image, presence: true


create_me:
  brand_id: 1
  image: MyString
  caption: MyString


@image_create = images(:create_me)
assert_no_difference('Image.count') do
  post images_url, xhr: true, params: { image: {brand_id: @image_create.brand_id, image: @image_create.image } }
end
```

running this test returns an error, as the controller does a `.save!`:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Image can't be blank
```

The curious thing is the same pattern exists for another class and the same test passes.

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  mount_uploader :image, DocumentUploader
  validates :image, presence: true

create_me:
  brand_id: 1
  image: MyString
  caption: MyString

@attachment_create = attachments(:create_me)
assert_no_difference('Attachment.count') do
  post attachments_url, xhr: true, params: { attachment: { caption: @attachment_create.caption, brand_id: @attachment_create.brand_id, image: @attachment_create.image } }
end
```

Both uploader classes function as per design in manual tests.

I can only surmise some confusion between the class name and the attribute name, but that is a wild assumption, given manual tests run properly.

What is causing this failure?  How should it be fixed?

Comment: Can you share the tests?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. The tests are given in the question (3rd block of each per-set class).  The validation error is generated via the controller line with `@image.save!`

Answer (score 0):

This may be one of two things
1- Could be naming conventions, have you tried changing the name of the attachment from `image` to something maybe like `img`?
2- I'm seeing a difference between the `Image` class and the `Attachment` class, which is in the mount_uploader used, one is using `DocumentUploader`, and the other is using `ImageUploader`.

Sorry couldn't put these in a comment to trace it with you, still new here and can only use answers.

Comment: I have attempted your suggestion (although I had not encountered this naming issue in the past).  Changing the attribute's name to ìmg` is still leading to a validation error `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Img can't be blank`   The fact that it is referred to as a Class is pointing somewhere...